# snprintf() returning inappropriate value

Tags: c++, printf

I've been looking over this piece of code for a while, and I can't seem to find my bug.  I think I know how `snprintf(dest, n, fmt, src)` is supposed to work ( it returns the number of remaining characters in the `src` buffer after filling the `dest` buffer with `n` characters from the `fmt` string and the `src` buffer) but it is not doing what I would expect.  Instead of returning the number of remaining characters to be copied, it is returning the **total** characters copied.

The code below:

```
 40   char header_file_name[200];
 ....
 87   int n_overflow = 0;
 88   n_overflow = snprintf( header_file_name, 200, "%s.h", template_name );
 89   if ( n_overflow > 0 )
 90   {
 91       printf( "That template name is too large; try a smaller template name\n");
 92       printf("n_overflow = %d\n", n_overflow);
 93       printf("header_file_name = %s\n", header_file_name );
 94       printf("length of header_file_name = %d\n", strlen(header_file_name));
 95       printf( "template_name = %s\n", template_name );
 96       printf("length of template_name = %d\n", strlen(template_name));
 97       exit(4);
 98   }
 99   if ( n_overflow < 0 )
100   {
101       printf( "An error occurred while handling your input; file: %s, line:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
102       exit(1);
103   }
```

outputs the following:

```
Compiling template file ABAQUS_Version_5.template
That template name is too large; try a smaller template name
n_overflow = 18
header_file_name = ABAQUS_Version_5.h
length of header_file_name = 18
template_name = ABAQUS_Version_5
length of template_name = 16
*** Error code 4
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "ABAQUS_Version_5.o"
```

What makes it so confusing is that my `dest` (`header_file_name`) has a length, and even has data in it after the `snprintf()` call, and my `src` (`template_name`) also has a length and is not `NULL`.  I've probably just made some gaff in my code, or I don't really understand `snprintf()`, and have been starring at it for too long.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's performing as documented.  Check the man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `snprintf` is supposed to do.

From `man snprintf` on an Ubuntu system: (emphasis added)

> The  functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` do not write more than `size` bytes (including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`)).  If the output was truncated due to this limit then  the  return  value  is  the  number  of  characters (excluding  the terminating null byte) which **would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available.**  Thus, a return value of `size` or more means that the output was  truncated.

Or, the even simpler wording from [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html#tag_16_159_04):

> Upon successful completion, the `snprintf()` function shall return the number of bytes that would be written to `s` had `n` been sufficiently large excluding the terminating null byte.

Comment: I must have misunderstood.  I thought that it would return 0 on successful printing to the buffer, -1 if it failed, and a positive number reflecting the amount of space the buffer would need to hold the rest of the data in the `src` buffer. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Makenbaccon: Two definitive references provided.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time.  I looked through them and see where I misread.  Thank you very much for your time and explanation.

Comment: So to check success, I should be comparing the return of `snprintf()`  with the value of `strlen(src)` + the number of not format characters in `fmt`.  Correct? I just want to make sure my understanding is right this time.

Comment: @Makenbaccon: You should check that the return value is not negative and that it is less than the `size` argument you passed to `snprintf`. That's what the GNU manpage suggests, in the last sentence. Usually, you would use the return value to reallocate the buffer before trying again.